# Include dimension letters L/W/H to WooCommerce formatted product dimensions output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

I'm trying to modify dimensions output that everywhere where **`get_dimensions()`** is called instead of default it would include letter of dimension.

So it would be 1 L x 1 W x 1 H instead of 1 x 1 x 1

Can I overwrite **`get_dimensions()`** function and include letter alongside each value in array or I can somehow use **`wc_format_dimensions()`** to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:** You can't override [**`get_dimensions()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_dimensions) **`WC_Product`** method.

But you can use **`woocommerce_format_dimensions`** filter hook located in [**`wc_format_dimensions()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_format_dimensions.html#1258-1275) function, to add custom labels to each dimension product attribute, this way *(just as you want)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function custom_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) );
    $label_with_dimensions = []; // Initialising

    // Loop Though dimensions array
    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention )
        $label_with_dimensions[$key] = strtoupper( substr($key, 0, 1) ) . ' ' . $dimention;

    return implode( ' x ',  $label_with_dimensions) . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce versions 3+ and works

Comment: Works perfect. Not sure if should create separate question, but how I could rename "length" key to "diameter". I think that could replace in $dimensions array using array_map ? Tried couple things, but got "Illegal string offset" warning.

Comment: @Aivaras Is better to ask this in a new question, may be adding to it this code explaining what you get now and then what you would like to get … or something like. I will answer (and may be others too), because is not possible to include my answer as a comment. Also try to be explicit explaining where do you want to rename that (where is going to appear)…

Answer (score -1):

```
$dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();

if ( !empty( $dimensions) ) {

echo 'Height: ' . $product->get_height() . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );

echo 'Width: ' . $product->get_width() . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );

echo 'Length: ' . $product->get_length() . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );

}
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this code change the output in **all places** where `get_dimensions` is called?