# WooCommerce: Customize product dimension output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, implode

I'm trying to change how the product dimensions are displayed in WooCommerce using  [Include dimension letters L/W/H to WooCommerce formatted product dimensions output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399170/include-dimension-letters-l-w-h-to-woocommerce-formatted-product-dimensions-outp/45400413#45400413) answer code.

It displays the dimensions the way I would like, unfortunately the code has a couple of issues. The code below throws a PHP error:

> PHP Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

It also does not display N/A when no product variation has been selected (it is just blank).

I have attempted to resolve these issues, but am not very familiar with WordPress and haven't been able to figure out the solution.

Thank you in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: I have updated my answer code to avoid the error…

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `$label_with_dimensions` is not an array.

Try defining it like below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function custom_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
   if ( empty( $dimension_string ) ) {
      return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
   }

   $label_with_dimensions = array();
   $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) );
   foreach( $dimensions as $key => $dimention ) {
      $label_with_dimensions[$key] = strtoupper( substr($key, 0, 1) ) . ' ' . $dimention;
   }

      return implode( ' x ',  $label_with_dimensions) . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
}
```

Have you printed `$dimensions` to see what it contains?
If not, try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($dimensions); echo '</pre>'`.

You also mentioned the "N/A" not getting displayed. Please check the usage of the `empty` function here: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.empty.php  This functions returns "TRUE" only if the variable you pass to it is equal to "FALSE" or 0.